# Rails jsonb query returns empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to query a datatype in my jsonb column. When I query with standard SQL, the response is empty. I was using [this as a reference.](https://gist.github.com/mankind/1802dbb64fc24be33d434d593afd6221)

My data: `id: "f0242deb-fef5-4221-b4eb-68610d355a06", metadata: {"classification"=>"unclassified"}`

My controller query: `Transaction.where('metadata @> ?', {classification: 'unclassified'}.to_json)`

I get this as a response `Transaction Load (39.0ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE (metadata @> '{"classification":"unclassified"}') => []`

I would expect the response to include the above dataset since the `classification` matches. Where am I going wrong?

Schema and models for reference.

```
schema.rb
create_table "transactions", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.jsonb "metadata", default: "{}", null: false
  t.index ["metadata"], name: "index_transactions_on_metadata", using: :gin
end
```

```
transaction.rb
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  require 'json'
  include ActiveModel::Serialization

  serialize :metadata
  store_accessor :metadata, :classification, :amount, :merchant, :category

  validates :transaction_date, :classification, :amount, :merchant, :category, presence: true

end
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is `json serialization`, it looks like this will force convert the input json data, take a look (on my project):

```rb
> Event.create(payload: {question: "jsonb index", answer: "json serialize"})
> ... ["payload", "\"---\\n:question: jsonb index\\n:answer: json serialize\\n\""]
```

in database, that payload will be saved as: `"---\n:question: jsonb index\n:answer: json serialize\n"`, and the jsonb query can not find it.

Now change the serializer

```rb
#require 'json'
#include ActiveModel::Serialization
serialize :payload, HashSerializer
store_accessor :payload, :question, :answer
```

the payload will be saved as `{"answer": "serialize", "question": "jsonb index"}` and jsonb query can find it.

Of course it also works if i remove `serialize`

> Keep in mind that database adapters handle certain serialization tasks for you. For instance: `json` and `jsonb` types in PostgreSQL will be converted between JSON object/array syntax and Ruby `Hash` or `Array` objects transparently. There is no need to use #serialize in this case.

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong as I haven't looked into it at all but that serialization looks like YAML.

Comment: @engineersmnky i not sure but maybe `ActiveModel::Serialization` format the input json like that before save to db